# Where can I get a list of command options for bitcoind and primcoind?

Tags: bitcoind, primecoind

I just installed bitcoind and primecoind on my ubuntu server. I was wondering where can i get all the command options for these daemons. The --help list does not display everything on primecoind as i dont even see the option "listaccounts" there. How else can i get a list of these options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the commands are well documented online at https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list

primecoind is a fork of bitcoind (although it might be via litecoind) and the commands for most of these coin daemons is the same. primecoind has a couple of options specifically for the generation of coins, which isn't really supported in most other coin daemons.

Answer (score 4):

`bitcoind help` lists the RPC commands. `listaccounts` is a RPC command. `bitcoind --help` lists the commandline options to the program itself.

EDIT:
You can also use `bitcoind help [RPC command]` for a brief description.